# Update DOM in Ruby on Rails 5

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, dom, ruby-on-rails-5

Have a problem with my app on ruby on rails 5, after ajax request cannot run javascript. I think this is problem with DOM, but I not have a good knowledge with JavaScript and cannot fix this problem. Will be very
appreciation everyone who will try to help me.

> movies_controller.rb

```
 def home
if params[:search]
  @movies = Movie.search(params[:search]).order('created_at DESC').page(params[:page]).per(20)
  @movies = @movies.genre(params[:genre]).order('created_at DESC').page(params[:page]).per(20)
  @movies = @movies.date_relist(params[:date_relist]).order('created_at DESC').page(params[:page]).per(20)
  @movies = @movies.rating(params[:rating]).order('created_at DESC').page(params[:page]).per(20)
else
  @movies = Movie.all.order('created_at DESC').page(params[:page]).per(20)
  @movies_genre = Movie.all.select(:genre).uniq.order('genre ASC')
  @date_relist = Movie.all.select(:date_relist).uniq.order('date_relist DESC')
  @rating = (Movie.all.select(:rating).uniq).order('rating DESC')
end
```

end

> home.html.erb

```
<div class="container">
<%= form_for root_path, method: :get, id: "movies_search", remote: true do %>
<%= label_tag :search %>
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search]%>
<%= label_tag :genre %>
<%= select_tag :genre, options_from_collection_for_select(@movies_genre, "genre", "genre") %>
<%= label_tag :date_relist %>
<%= select_tag :date_relist, options_from_collection_for_select(@date_relist, "date_relist", "date_relist"), include_blank: true %>
  <%= label_tag :rating %>
<%= select_tag :rating, options_from_collection_for_select(@rating, "rating", "rating"), include_blank: true %>
<%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil  %>
```

```
<div class="content">
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="movies"> <%= render partial: 'movies' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

> home.js.erb

```
$("#movies, .pagination").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("movies")) %>")
```

> _movies.html.erb

```
<% @movies.each do |m| %>

<div class="card">
  <div class="card__container card__container--closed">
    <svg class="card__image" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1920 1200" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice">
      <defs>
        <clipPath id="clipPath<%=m.id%>">
          <polygon class="clip" points="0,1200 0,0 1920,0 1920,1200"></polygon>
        </clipPath>
      </defs>
      <image clip-path="url(#clipPath<%=m.id%>)" width="1920" height="1200" xlink:href="/pictures/<%= m.img %>"></image>
    </svg>
    <div class="card__content">
      <i class="card__btn-close fa fa-times"></i>
      <div class="card__caption">
        <h2 class="card__title"><%= m.title %></h2>
        <p class="card__subtitle">Genre - <%= m.genre %></p>
      </div>
      <div class="card__copy">
        <div class="meta">
          <img class="meta__avatar" src="/pictures/<%= m.img %>" alt="author01" />
          <img class="krug"/>
          <div class="description">
            <span class="meta__author">Running Time - <%= m.runtime %></span><br>
            <span class="meta__date">Release Date - <%= m.date_relist %></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="text" style="text-align: center">
          <p>
            <%= raw(m.trailer) %>
            <br>
            <%= m.desc %>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your jQuery selector is `#movies, .pagination` yet I do not see any element with `pagination` class in your templates. Could you clarify what are you trying to accomplish with that jQuery selector?

Comment: There's some downright bizarre code in the controller there. Why is `@movies` being redefined, repaginated, and reordered so many times? If you want to chain filters together usually you do that without pagination. As in: `Movie.search(params[:search]).genre(params[:genre]).date_relist(params[:date_relist]).rating(params[:rating]).order('created_at DESC').page(params[:page]).per(20)` where you can format that over multiple lines for clarity.

Comment: Pagination I temporarily deleted, this right now is not interesting for me.